# Need to prepare a ranklist in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table which has all the details of a student. I have prepared a ranklist procedure for the same.
For example:

```
SELECT name, total_marks, @curRank := IF(@prevVal=total_marks, @curRank, @curRank+1) AS rank,
@prevVal:=total_marks
FROM marks, (
SELECT @curRank :=0, @prevVal:=null, @n:=1
) r
ORDER BY total_marks DESC ;
```

Here in this statement. I need to check whether any student has the same rank. If so then I have to check a particular subject marks and sort it accordingly.

Comment: I want to know that your marks table contains one entry for one student or it has multiple entries for each student.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this -

```
SELECT rank, GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM (
  -- your query goes here
  ...
  ...
  ...
) t
GROUP BY rank
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE marks(
  name VARCHAR(20),
  z INT(10),
  y INT(10),
  total_marks INT(10),
  rank INT(10)
);

INSERT INTO marks (name, z, y, total_marks, rank) VALUES ('abc', 100, 50, 150, 1);
INSERT INTO marks (name, z, y, total_marks, rank) VALUES ('abc', 100, 50, 150, 2);
INSERT INTO marks (name, z, y, total_marks, rank) VALUES ('abc', 100, 50, 150, 3);

INSERT INTO marks (name, z, y, total_marks, rank) VALUES ('def', 100, 50, 150, 1); 
INSERT INTO marks (name, z, y, total_marks, rank) VALUES ('def', 100, 50, 150, 2); 

INSERT INTO marks (name, z, y, total_marks, rank) VALUES ('abcdef', 100, 50, 150, 1);
INSERT INTO marks (name, z, y, total_marks, rank) VALUES ('abcdef', 100, 50, 150, 2);
INSERT INTO marks (name, z, y, total_marks, rank) VALUES ('abcdef', 100, 50, 150, 3);


SELECT rank, GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM (
  SELECT name, MAX(rank) rank FROM marks GROUP BY name) t
GROUP BY rank;

+------+--------------------+
| rank | GROUP_CONCAT(name) |
+------+--------------------+
|    2 | def                |
|    3 | abc,abcdef         |
+------+--------------------+
```

Users *abc* and *abcdef* have the same ranks (1,2,3).
User *def* has different ranks (1,2).

Comment: can u pls give specify the same as i am unable to get the correct result set

Comment: OK, please provide CREATE TABLE and some INSERT statements for your table to test the query.

Comment: create table marks ( name varchar(20),z int(10).y int(10),total_marks int(10),rank int(10)) this is the table insert statements are insert into marks(name,z,y,total_marks,rank) values('abc',100,50,150,'');,insert into marks(name,z,y,total_marks,rank) values('def',100,50,150,'');

Comment: Check the answer. Is that what you need?